# jQuery: Trap all click events before they happen?

Tags: jquery, events, click, propagation

On my page I have a lot of various elements which respond to click events.
There are times when I need to block all clicks based on some global flag.
Is there a way I can make this check in a centralized location?

Right now in each event I check for the flag, for example:

```
var canClick = false; // Global flag

// Sample click event:
$("#someDiv").click(function(){
  if(!canClick) return;

  // Some stuff ...
});
```

What I'd like to do is have one element which traps all click events *before* any other elements.

I tried doing it on *document* but these events only occur after the other click events.

Example:

```
$("#someDiv").click(function(){ console.log("someDiv click"); });

$(document).click(function(){ console.log("Document click"); });

// When I click on the someDiv element it prints:
> someDiv click
> Document click
```

I also tried putting a full screen div on top of everything and using this to trap events but the problem there was that none of the clicks were being propagated through this full screen div.  Also I don't want to rely on creating extra elements to trap clicks as it feels a little hacky.

Could I maybe overwrite the jQuery click function so that I can put my little check in there?

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, use .addEventListener() and set the 3rd option to **true**.  This will bind the listener to the capture phase and execute the function before anything else gets executed.

Here's an example where this will stop all click handlers from executing:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLwMh/1/

Comment: Ahh brilliant!  Thank you very much kind sir.  Works in Chrome 11, that's the only browser I need it to be compatible with.  Cheers.

Comment: For anyone that needs cross-browser compatibility, this isn't supported by IE<9

Comment: How to do this with an element?

Answer (score 0):

You could capture all the click events then trigger a custom event where you have your listeners bound after your check

```
$("#someDiv").bind('awesomeEvent', function() {
    //do stuff here
}

$(*).click(function() {
    if(canClick) {
        $(this).trigger('awesomeEvent');
    }
}
```

EDIT
I should mention that using the $(*) selector is not a good idea from a performance standpoint.  You should really try and narrow the scope somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Using Inject Javascript :

```
view.loadUrl(
                    "javascript:(function() {"


                            + "document.addEventListener('click', function(e)"
                            + "{"
                            + "e.stopPropagation();"
                            + "}"
                            + ", true);"

                            + "})()"
            );
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Please [edit] your answer to ensure that it improves upon other answers already present in this question.

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation or details to your answer. While it might answer the question, just adding a piece of code as an answer, doesn't per say help OP or future community members understand the issue or the proposed solution.